# accessing admin attribute and admin? method in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, admin

Iam trying to access the admin? method which was generated when I added the admin attribute to my database . Iam trying to use it in my _header partial to display a different navbar for admin users.

Iam requiring the User class in the application controller so that I may use its methods across my rails app as such

'''
require User
'''

I have also tried to wrap my user class in module named UserMod

and require it in application controller as well

'''
require UserMod

'''

yet when I try to us it in my header partial : app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb

````
```
 <% if current_user && current_user.admin? %>
            <li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>
        <%end%>

```
````

it produces the error :

'''
uninitialized constant
'''

when I do not require or include any classes or modules in the application controller it says that admin? method is not recognized.

Can anyone please assist me expand the scope of the the admin? method across my application.
Thank you so much!

Comment: You don't need to `require User` to handle users in a controller level. Could you add the whole `uninitialized constant` error you're getting to your question? Also that `admin` is a boolean field for user? or is an extra method you defined in the model? could you share that code to give more context?

Comment: the error is: '''NameError: uninitialized constant SessionsController::UserMod''', I have a boolean field as well as method that is apparently generated when I create the migration to add the admin column to my table. This is according to ruby one rails tutorial by Michale hartl. iam trying to access that admin? method that is available in the. model. Thank you

Comment: No idea what tutorial you're talking about. Have you run the migrations? if you call in a `rails console` something like `User.last.admin?` is that working? how about removing the `?` sign, what is displaying in that case?

Comment: yes I have run the migrations. When I run User.last.admin?  the following error is produced. ''' Zeitwerk::NameError (expected file /Users/ariticas/nfs_clone/DFS/app/models/user.rb to define constant User, but didn't) "'

Comment: Could you add to your question how you're using that `Zeitwerk` gem? probably that's where the issue is. Also check in the logs of the error the file and line where the error is raised and share it